# indexes in sql server, internal working and structure of indexes

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, internal, clustered-index

when we create a clustered index **CIX_FirstNames** on a column , say, **FirstNames**, then what actually happens internally in SQL Server?

i have read that clustered indexes create copy of the data.

so, does sql server creates a new index table, **IndexTable** , and copies all the FirstNames from the table into **IndexTable**, and when a firstname is searched, then it displays it from the index table?

is this the actual working of clustered indexes ?

Comment: You **absolutely need** to study this great intro article [SQL Server Index Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/) - it explains the index structures and shows diagrams to visualize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way too big a topic to handle here in a quick answer - you need to get yourself:

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243)

[image]

which covers this all in great detail.

But just briefly: **NO!** creating a clustered index does **NOT** duplicate data! Where did you get that from??

What a clustered index does is reorder the data (according to the key), and the leaf-level nodes of the clustered index **are the data pages** - but those exist only once.

Some more resources of interest:

- [Kimberly Tripp on Index Internals](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/Indexes-in-SQL-Server-20052008-Part-2-Internals-.aspx)
- [Kalen Delaney Workshop on Index Internals](http://www.vconferenceonline.com/event/home.aspx?id=130)
- [SQL Server Indexes: AN Introduction](http://www.petri.co.il/introduction-to-sql-server-indexes.htm)
- [Introduction to Indexes](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/68439/)
- [Stairway to SQL Server Indexes: an Introduction](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/72284/)

Comment: so is a copy of the data made when a non-clustered index is created?

Comment: @marc_s:but sir, in clustered indexes, sql does not needs to go the table to get the data,
it gets it from the index itself, so if the copy of the data is not in the index then how does it shows the data without going to the table?

Comment: when a table is created and data is inserted, then the data is contained in the data pages, and as you told, leaf level nodes of CI are data pages, so are these data pages those pages where the data is inserted.?

Comment: @sqlchild: yes, the leaf level nodes of the clustered index **are the data pages** - not a copy of the data pages - there is no copy.

Comment: @sqlchild: a non-clustered index will copy those columns that are part of the index. If you index on (FirstName), then yes - the index pages of that NC index will contain the FirstName values as a copy.

Comment: @marc_s: ok sir, so NON-C.I.s have index pages , and CIs have Data Pages. am i right?

Comment: @sqlchild: all indexes have index pages - that's their whole point. The difference between a CI and a NCI index is in the leaf level - while a normal NCI index has just another set of index entries there (which point to the actual data), in the CI, the leaf level nodes **are** the data - no "points to the data" - it **IS** the data

Comment: @marc_so, so there's no leaf level in NONCIs and data pages are also not there?

Comment: @sqlchild: yes, of course NCI have a leaf level - every tree does. But in a NCI, that leaf level contains "normal" index entries like all the other levels, too. And yes, the NCI does **not** contain the whole data pages - it's merely a pointer to the clustered index where the data pages are located. Read the book!

Answer (score 0):

Indexing views will duplicate data.

> "The downside to this is that the indexed view is a full copy of the
>   data from the underlying tables[...]"

http://strangenut.com/blogs/dacrowlah/archive/2008/11/26/creating-an-indexed-view-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008.aspx