# Why a separate index table is needed

Tags: database, indexing

I was reading about Indexes in databases.

First, I have my original table. Then I add another table (the index table), which, every time I add a row in the first table, I make the effort of knowing where to insert it in the index table (say alphabetically). Then, when I search for some record, I use the index table, which transforms my searching problem to O(log) instead of O(n).

My question is the following: why not doing that effort in the original table?. At least if that table have only one index. If it has more, then apply the idea of tables of indexes. At least this idea is never mentioned in the literature I read, and I thought maybe there's a good reason.

Comment: And that is, indeed, why most database products have a concept like [clustered indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post has some very useful links: [indexes in sql server, internal working and structure of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402112/indexes-in-sql-server-internal-working-and-structure-of-indexes)

Short answer: The clustered index on your table should not be creating a separate mapping, as it sorts the original table itself. The other indices would create mappings to the row ids of the clustered one. This could be different based on the DB you are reading about.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how indexes are normally done on databases - normally a table has its indexes, and the database server will automatically try to use the best index, when the query allows - for example, if you have a `Name` column indexed, and you do a select where the name is an exact match(`= 'foo'`), it'll use your index; if you did a query where it starts with a specific string (`LIKE 'foo%'`), it may choose to use your index; whilst if you do a query where the indexed column contains a substring (`LIKE '%foo%'`) then it cannot use that index, and would have to scan the entire table.

Comment: I think your reply don't answer my question. I agree all what you say, but I'm asking the "why" of having another table of indexes instead of doing the same effort done on inserting directly in the original table.

Comment: And I'm saying "you don't have **another** table"